# Group By Using Looping

Tags: r

I have a data set where i need to obtain sum of various variables by grouping it by a variable in R. The data set is as follows:

```
V1 V2 V3 V4
1  2   3 a
5  6   7 a
3  2   3 b
5  6   7 b
```

I want the output in the form:

```
V1 V2 V3 V4
6  8  10  a
8  8  10  b
```

I want to use a loop for doing this. It will be great if someone can help

Answer (score 0):

you can use dplyr library do that

```
library("dplyr")
df <- data.frame(V1 = c(1,5,3,5), V2 = c(2,6,2,6), V3 = c(3,7,3,7), V4 = c("a","a","b","b")
res_df <- df %>% group_by(V4) %>% summarise(V1=sum(V1),V2=sum(V2),V3=sum(V3))
```

Comment: You should use `summarise_each(funs(sum))` here.

Comment: I tried the `summarise_each`, however, I get the following error `error in UseMethod("group_by_")`